# What is the algorithm of pytorch tensor sort

Tags: pytorch

Is there anybody who knows sorting algorithm of pytorch?

I want to implement sorting function as same as [`torch.sort()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sort.html#torch.sort) but I can't find related source.

and [this code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/Sorting.cpp) doesn't seem to be used for sorting.